# Where is Act 3's Blaze of Glory event?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In what zone does each event occur in?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67695/in-what-zone-does-each-event-occur-in)

The best I can surmise for its location is that it's on a bridge somewhere. Which bridge, and when is it available?

[image: Blaze of Glory]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]In act 3 half way up Rakkis Crossing. Look for a NPC named Captain Haile. He will start the event.

Comment: Is this usually left or right of the Rakkis Crossing waypoint? And is the event rare? I don't think I've ever seen it before