# Where are the Act 2 events?

Tags: diablo-iii

There are nine events in Act II: **Restless Sands, Crumbling Vault, Prisoners of Kamyr, Shrine of Rakanishu, Lost Treasure of Khan Dakab, A Miner's Gold, Lair of the Lacuni, Rygnar Idol, and Guardian Spirits**. I'm still missing the last few. Where are these events, and what are their spawn conditions? (If in a specific zone, what are their common spawn regions within that zone?)

Comment: Instead of making one of each of these (lore books, events, world books) for each act, why not consolidate the info in a single topic?

Comment: Since the lore books and event locations need more detail than [a list](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/66418/21177) can provide , I thought it'd be best to ask by Act. (I'm not sure the other Acts need event lists, as they have fewer, though every Act could probably use a [lore book listing](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/69132/21177)—feel free to edit the question into something broader if you feel it's appropriate.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [In what zone does each event occur in?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67695/in-what-zone-does-each-event-occur-in)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### **Act II**

Howling Plateau:
- A Miner's Gold
- Lair of the Lacuni

Stinging Winds:
- The Crumbling Vault
- The Restless Sands
- Guardian Sands
- The Rygnar Idol

Dahlgur Oasis:
- Prisoners of Kamyr
- Shrine of Rakanishu
- Lost Treasure of Khan Dakab