# Diablo 3 Side quests list

Tags: diablo-iii

In every act how many Diablo 3 Side quests are there? I have stumbled across a few but im not sure if i have missed any??

And advice would be much appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [In what zone does each event occur in?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67695/in-what-zone-does-each-event-occur-in)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

If by the side quests you mean the events that are located randomly through out your game. They are listed in the Campaign Section of the Achievements assorted by Acts.

Also here is an incomplete list and location for some. http://www.gamefront.com/diablo-3-side-quest-list-locations/